# "find: .: No such file or directory" while using find on the current directory

Tags: find

Find command seems not to work at all. For example, I'm in a directory where there absolutely is file named index.php and I execute this:

```
[root@server htdocs]# find . -name "index.php"
find: .: No such file or directory
```

I always get this no such file or directory error.

No matter what path I define, or what file I search for, I always get this error. I'm pretty sure that I'm overlooking something very simple. Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
[root@server htdocs]# pwd
/srv/www/htdocs
[root@server htdocs]# type -a find
find is /usr/bin/find
[root@server htdocs]# ls -la | grep index.php
-rw-rw-r--  1 andris users  413 Sep  1  2013 index.php
[root@server htdocs]# find . -name "index.php"
find: .: No such file or directory
[root@server htdocs]# find .
.
find: .: No such file or directory

[root@server htdocs]# stat .
  File: `.'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: ca00h/51712d    Inode: 155686      Links: 12
Access: (0775/drwxrwxr-x)  Uid: (  504/  andris)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Access: 2014-06-17 19:37:22.000000000 +0000
Modify: 2014-06-08 21:06:16.000000000 +0000
Change: 2014-06-08 21:06:16.000000000 +0000

[root@server htdocs]# find --version
GNU find version 4.2.27
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION SELINUX
```

`strace find .` output: https://gist.github.com/andrisp/f3adaf740548eead33da

```
[root@server htdocs]# find . -noleaf -name "index.php"
find: .: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What does `ls -la|grep "index.php"` say?

Comment: `find .` doesn't work either? What about `ls -al`?

Comment: `[root@server htdocs]# ls -la | grep "index.php"`
-rw-rw-r--  1 andris users  413 Sep  1  2013 index.php`

Comment: sorry, for multiple edits - struggling with comment markdown for code.

Comment: `find .` outputs the same error

Comment: Nothing wrong with multiple edits, don't worry about it. You can find some help on the markdown syntax [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). Also, please [edit] your question and add the output of `pwd` and `type -a find`.

Comment: The `.: No such file or directory` suggests there is something seriously wrong with the directory if it cannot be found via its `.` hardlink. On Linux with GNU `find` I get `find: `.': Permission denied` if I don't have read of execute rights for the current directory (happens if I `cd` to it before changing the permissions). A different system or `find` might give a different message, otherwise I think this is a likely a filesystem or deeper system error. Try doing `ls .` to see if you get the same error, if so I would do an `fsck` if possible.

Comment: @Graeme `ls .` works (outputs file list)

Comment: Does `stat .` work? Also, what happens if you use `find /srv/www/htdocs -name index.php`?

Comment: The fact that `find .` finds the `.` entry, *then* complains that it doesn't exist is curious. Seemingly this is a bug with `find`, which version are you using?

Comment: Can you post the output of `strace find .` somewhere?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas @celtschk @Graeme updated my description with version, `stat .` and `strace find .`

Comment: What happens when you `-noleaf`? See `man find` and type `/leaf` then `ENTER`. I think that a combination of GNU `find`'s search optimizations and ACLs on your filesystem are effecting your problem.

Comment: @mikeserv updated description

Comment: Your filesystem is NFS I guess? Or something like it? The find calls seem to be linking the `.` link into `/proc` it looks like... I now suspect *especially* ACLs, though I guess the leafing doesn't matter... or some strange shared mount context I guess...

Comment: @mikeserv it's ext3, but i have enabled ACL on it without really knowing what I'm doing :), so it's probably the reason. Will try to disable it and see what happens

Comment: That's probably a good idea. And, if it works, please upvote @vadimbog as his answer is essentially correct. An easier way to check is to mount that disk elsewhere like `mount -o noacl /dev/${disk} /else/where` and see what you get. I *think* that's enough to verify it, though it could be that initial `/etc/selinux.conf` thing could interfere...

Comment: Can you include the output of `cat /proc/mounts` so we know what the filesystem topology looks like?

Comment: There's something weird with that trace — jumping from `open(".")` (which succeeds) and `getdents` on it (normal) to `stat` on `/proc/something` (unexpected). Do you see weird behavior in any other directory? Do you see weird behavior with programs other than `find` (e.g. `ls`)? What does `find .` (no other argument) say? Is it different if you call `find` with the full path to that directory? Is SELinux in enforcing mode, and if so do any messages appear in the logs? What distribution is this?

Comment: I noticed that SELinux is being used. I'm sure that's the root of your problem.  To be more specific, the labeling of `find` probably doesn't match that of `/srv/www/htdocs`.  Could you repeat the experiment with SELinux deactivated?

Answer (score 2):

According to your `strace` output, and I have no idea about the reason, the `open()` function prefix filenames with `/proc/` :

```
open(".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY) = 4
fcntl64(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC) = 0
getdents64(4, /* 21 entries */, 32768) = 664
getgid32() = 0
stat64("/proc/index.php", 0xbfc53bd0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getgid32() = 0
stat64("/proc/.svn", 0xbfc53bd0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getgid32() = 0
stat64("/proc/init-dist.php", 0xbfc53bd0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getgid32() = 0
stat64("/proc/landing-page.html", 0xbfc53bd0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getgid32() = 0
[...]
stat64("/proc/js", 0xbfc53bd0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getgid32() = 0
stat64("/proc/extras", 0xbfc53bd0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getgid32() = 0
stat64("/proc/sitemaps", 0xbfc53bd0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
getdents64(4, /* 0 entries */, 32768) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I've see this happen on Mac when the directory is on removable media which has been removed and readded since the terminal window was opened. I can't explain why (probably has to do with information cached when the terminal session was started), but it was reproducible. Just restarted the terminal session and all was fine.

Comment: Similarly I'm seeing this on a mac where the current directory is getting updated by rsync.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the absolute path like:

```
   sudo find /where/your_file_is/located/ -iname "index.php"
```

And as already mentioned above it might be that you do not have permissions.
What happens if you:

```
ls .
```

Does your shell know what to do with the dot?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an ancient version of SunOS. SunOS 4.1.3 to be exact. SMH.

The reason I was getting "no such file or directory" was because it was stumbling upon symbolic links.

I thought perhaps the permissions issue mentioned above was the cause, so I ran my command as root and still got it.

Looking at one of the files it stumbled upon, I saw that it was a symbolic link; so I tried adding -follow to the command. No joy.

I'm rusty with Unix scripting, so I'm exploring my options.

My original command:

```
find . -exec grep ai1212.pic {} \; -print
```

My updated command, having no such errors:

```
find . ! -type l -exec grep ai1212.pic {} \; -print
```

The '!' negates an option and 'l' is a symbolic link. I do not know if this holds within Linux or not.

Answer (score -1):

You might not have execution permission for your user for the directory you are searching from. Does it have read and execute permission?

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
$ find ~/ -type f -name "MYFILE"
```

The best way to search for file or folder is :

- `updatedb`      (for updating system file index).
- `locate Myfile`

Comment: Note that using `updatedb` and `locate` require that a package which provides both to be installed (e.g., `mlocate`).

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago).
You could make sure you are using the right find either `/usr/bin` or `/bin` to make sure the find command is there.
If you can not even do a `man` on `find`, try changing your shell to either `/bin/ksh` or `/bin/bash`.
I have found that environment variables and paths can get confused once in awhile.

Answer (score -1):

As others have mentioned, using the full path to the find binary may help. It's possible find is aliased with additional flags on your system. Typing `\find` will prevent any aliases from being used as well. You can also use `alias` to view command aliases in your current shell session.